# How to nest navigator inside a RealmProvider?

Tags: mongodb, react-native, navigation, realm

The problem seems pretty simple. I want my ToDo screen to have access to the RealmProvider. The issue is I don't have access to the navigator in the LoginScreen when called as fallback for UserProvider. Here is my main App function:

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <AppProvider id={"devicesync - xxxxx"}>
      <UserProvider fallback={LoginScreen}>
        <RealmProvider
          schema={[Task]}
          sync={{
            flexible: true,
          }}
        >
          <NavigationContainer>
            <Stack.Navigator>
              <Stack.Screen name="LoginScreen" component={LoginScreen} />
              <Stack.Screen name="TodoList" component={ToDoScreen} />
            </Stack.Navigator>
          </NavigationContainer>
        </RealmProvider>
      </UserProvider>
    </AppProvider>
  );
}
```

Any ideas?

I have tried various navigation implementations to no avail. Primarily the following in my LoginScreen.jsx file:

`const navigation = useNavigation();`